# PySimpleGUI ASCII Art won't display properly

Tags: python, pysimplegui, ascii-art

I am currently making a project and utilizing PySimpleGUI for my GUI. I am wanting to display ASCII ART however it is not properly displaying. To my reasoning is due to the characters being properly displayed however the spaces get condensed down when transferred over and displayed. Thus causing it to be malformed.

Image of results:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUI5n.png)
Code:

```
def EnumResults():

sg.theme('DarkPurple6')


ART = """ 


    ..  . .....   . .....   ......    .....     .....     ....   . .....   . ....   
    ..   .......   .....     .....     ....     .....   . .....   .......   ..... . 
    ..../#################################################################(,  ....
    . ..@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@, ...
    ..  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@/. . 
    ..  @@@@@@@,.  ........  ..... ..  ..... .. ...... ......... .......&@@@@@@/. . 
    ..@@@@@@@,.....  . .... .  ...... .  .....  .  .....  . .....   . &@@@@@@/....
    . ..@@@@@@@,.... .  .....  .  .....  . .....   . .....   ......    .&@@@@@@/ ...
    ..  @@@@@@@.  . ......  ...... .  .....  .  .....  .  .....  . .....&@@@@@@/. . 
    ... @@@@@@@..  .....  .  .....  .  .....  . .....   . .....   ......&@@@@@@/.   
    ..@@@@@@@,.....  ...... .  ...... .  .....  .  .....  . ......  . &@@@@@@/....
    .  .@@@@@@@. .. .....  ........  ...... .  ...... .  .....  .  .....&@@@@@@/..  
    ..  @@@@@@@.  . ......  ...... .  .....  .  .....  .  .....  . .....&@@@@@@/. . 
    ...@@@@@@@,....  .  .....  . ......   ..... .   ..... .  .....  .  &@@@@@@/ ...
    ..@@@@@@@,.....  ...... .  ...... .  .....  .  .....  . ......  . &@@@@@@/....
    .. .@@@@@@@. .  .....  . ......    .... .   ..... .  .....  .  .....&@@@@@@/..  
    ..  @@@@@@@,  . ......   ..... .  .....  .  .....  .  .....  . .....&@@@@@@/. . 
    ..@@@@@@@,....  .  .....    ......   ..... .   ..... .  .....  .  &@@@@@@/ ...
    ..@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@/....
    .. .@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@/..  
    ..  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@.  #@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@/. . 
    ..@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@/ ...
    ..@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@/....
    ..  .@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@*...  
    ..  . ......  . .... .  ...... .(@@@@@@@@@@@@@@..  .  .....  . ......  . .... . 
    ....     .....   . .....   ...(@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  ..... .  .....     .....    ...
    .....  . ......   ..... .   ..(@@@@@@@@@@@@@@  .....  . ......  . ......  ....
    ..  . .....   . .....   .%@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@....     .....     .....  
    ..  . ......  . .... .  ...... .   ....  .  .....  .  .....  . ......  ...... . 
    ....   . .....   . .....   .......   ..... .   ..... .  .....  .  .....    ...
        


    """

layout = [
    
        
        [sg.Text("Coyote", size=(40, 1), font=('Any 15'))],
        [sg.Image(source='images/desktop.png', size=(300,100))],
        [sg.Text(ART, auto_size_text=True )],
        [sg.Text("Results from enumeration")],
        [sg.Output(size=(100,30))],
        [sg.Button("Display", key="-ESEND-", bind_return_key=True)],
        [sg.Button("Exit", button_color=('white', 'firebrick3'), key='Exit') ]
        
        
        ]
window = sg.Window("Results Window", layout, icon='images/Coyote.ico', no_titlebar=True, grab_anywhere=True, element_justification='c', alpha_channel=.9)
choice = None
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "-ESEND-":
        
        nmr = ps.read_csv('nmapdump.csv', sep = ';', header = 0)
        print( "\n", nmr[['protocol', 'port', 'name', 'state', 'reason']])
        for i in nmr.index:
            print(nmr['port'][i])
        
    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are ASSUMING the use of a fixed-width font.  Most fonts have variable-width glyphs, and will look awful (in different ways).  I don't know what font "Any 15" picks, but you may need to force the use of, for example, "Courier 15".

Comment: @TimRoberts Well sir, your advice was fruitful. The image properly displays. This shall allow me to build the dankest app, thank you again!

Comment: Maybe take a look at the psgfiglet repo under the PySimpleGUI GitHub for an example of using fixed-width fonts to make ASCII art.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mentioned in the comments using a fix-width font, just as the other responders that commented before I did.  I wanted to show the result of using Courier.

There are 2 PySimpleGUI "Demo Programs" that may be of interest.  One is Demo_pyfiglet.  The other is Demo_OpenCV_Webcam_ASCII.  Both can be found in the PySimpleGUI Repo.

They both simply use the courier font as it's likely on every platform.  It's on Android for example when using pydroid3 in addition to the usual Windows, Mac and Linux.

[image]
[image]